# how to place two divs side by side

Tags: html, css

How can I place 2 divs side by side, both which have images. I want the divs to remain side by side and the images auto size ,with screen size.When I reduce the size of the screen the images re-position themselves one below the other. 
How will be the css for the below html?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
      <img src="img1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <img src="img2.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using bootstrap grid's. It can be something like this.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://www.thebrandbite.com/wp-content/media/2015/07/apple-7.jpg" width="30%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/KRLMkuaBjm5mKDDP" width="30%">      
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/jwMc35QuEy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `float` to get contained elements to sit either side

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"><img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/></div>
  <div class="right"><img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/></div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: You can use `Flex-Box`

```css
.container {
   width: 100vw;
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-items: center;
   align-content: space-around;
 }

 .container > img {
   align-self: auto;
   margin: 4px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/>
</div>
```